# Ротация цифр на CSS

Tags: css

Здравствуйте, не получается найти каким способом на некоторых сайтах осуществляется ротация цифр. Например: "У нас 9 857 компаний" и это число при появлении на экране изменяется от 1 до необходимого числа. Можно ли это сделать на чистом CSS?

Comment: http://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/pen/ImEtj?editors=1100 , ищите "css counter" примеров достаточно, просто настроить под себя!

Comment: Css не умеет генерировать контент. Менять цифры анимацией вы можете — просто. Однако, цифры надо сгенерировать. Не думаю, что вы пойдете на это, поэтому необходимо использовать JS-изменение контента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, на css нельзя, это делается на JS, на Jquery можно примерно так сделать:

```js
$('.counter').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter">1000</div>
<div class="counter">700</div>
<div class="counter">1500</div>
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю,что этот кусок можно вставить прямо в HTML код?

Comment: Можно, только между тегами  `<script></script>`

Comment: да, но у меня почему-то не срабатывает